# Does a foreground Activity always have the lowest OOM score?

Tags: android, memory-management, process, linux-kernel, foreground

I'm reading into the out-of-memory (OOM) killer now, as well as how Android prioritizes processes (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle)

It seems to be that foreground Activities should always have the lowest oom_score, and are hence always the last to be killed. However, I've come across cases where the launcher actually has a lower oom_score than the foreground Activity. Does anyone know why this behavior is so?

Answer (score 0):

Launcher will always have lowest oom_score than the foreground Activity, because the launcher should not been closed ever.

> And the main reason behind this is launcher is the app/screen which
>   get's launched (using [ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) intent) as first screen once device boots and also it's the
>   screen where you go after everything is closed.

Comment: That's not true in my experience. I'm looking at the oom_scores of processes in my Nexus 5 with Marshmallow, and most foreground Activities have a lower oom_score than the launcher. Some, however, don't, until I kill the foreground process and restart it.